# Running apps at scheduled times

Tags: file, batch-file, math

I'm running Windows 7. I need to run an application 3 times each day 8 hours apart.  The app needs to run within a window of `09:00-09:15`, `17:00-17:15` and `12:00-12:15`. It only takes about 1 minute to complete the task.  At the moment I'm trying to compare the current time to one of the time windows above then run the app.
Now when it runs, it goes directly to an 8 hour timeout routine.  I'm not sure how to make this work. 
I have both `:RUN` and `:TIMEOUT` routines which individually run fine.  I just can't get it to run at certain times.  This is my logic.

```
IF TIME GTR "0900" & IF TIME  LSS "0915"  GOTO RUN, GOTO TIMEOUT

IF TIME GTR "1700" & IF TIME  LSS "1715"  GOTO RUN, GOTO TIMEOUT

IF TIME GTR "1200" & IF TIME  LSS "1215" GOTO RUN, GOTO TIMEOUT
```

Comment: You should take a look at the Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: That's where I started but ran into the same problem with the schedule.    Whether I put all 3 times in one trigger or made different triggers for each of the 3 times, neither would work.  The times came and went but did not run the application.  That's why I went the batch file way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```bat
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('powershell get-date -format "HM"') do set currentTime=%%G

if %currentTime% gtr 900 (
   if %time% lss 915 (
       goto run

   )
)

if %currentTime% gtr 1700 (
   if %time% lss 1715 (
       goto run

   )
)

if %currentTime% gtr 1200 (
   if %time% lss 1215 (
       goto run
   )
)
```

Also, please move the `timeout` command to the end of the `:run` routine.

---

This script does:

- Gets the current time in `HM` format(trailing 0s removed)
- Compares the `HM` time with the pre-set time
- Execute the `goto` accordingly to the results.

Comment: Time variable is regionally dependent.  It may not output the same on the users computer as yours.

Comment: I understand that. Maybe I'll change it to `wmic`. Hopefully it will be regionally **in**dependent.

Comment: @Squashman I have edited the script so it should be regionally independent.

Comment: Thanks to all.  I would never have been able to write that code.  It works great!  I'm running the script now and it runs almost as expected.  It runs continuously regardless of the times required.
One question, do I need a powershell script?  If so, how would I set this up?  I've never used PS.

Comment: No need PS script. Just copy the code, and you are ready to go. And if you find it useful, feel free to upvote or accept my answer.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into my batch file, but it does not recognize the times to run.  It runs the app again after the TIMEOUT has expired rather than waiting for the next scheduled run time to run the app.

Comment: My code works completely fine, there may be some errors in your `:Timeout`, causing it to not wait until the next time period.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I really appreciate your help in the this. The only difference is my timeout routine is as follows.  I'll change it to the actual timeout and let it run overnight.  I'll let you know in tomorrow how it works.
:TIMEOUT 
REM timeout 480000 /nobreak 
REM This is my timeout for testing purposes.
timeout 40

GOTO REPEAT

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my needs properly.  I'm not familiar enough to follow this script so I have to rely upon your expertise.  I need my app to run within those times.  Like between 0900-0915 and so on.  Is this how this script runs?  And iin answer to your question, the :REPEAT is before your code.

Comment: Whenever my script runs, it gets the current time, and compare if it is in your designated time period. If so, execute the goto commands.

Comment: You are right.  Actually it seems to be the the :GOTO commands.  I set both GOTOs in the first section, 0900-0915, to goto :REPEAT.  This should be a loop to the beginning , and should not allow the script to continue to run the app, But the script still continues to run the app.

Comment: Squashman, Your routine works great.  It was my TIMEOUT that was the issue.  I wish I could give you 5 thumbs ups, but I'm not a member of the forum.  Thanks for your help.